# Access violation when creating a mesh and launching the window SDL/GLEW C++

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew

I am currently following along on an openGL course and when organising my code into classes, I am getting an access violation error along with this on the console terminal.
SDL window creation failed! (I programmed it to output that when the window cannot be created)

Here's my code:
main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include "Window.h"
#include "Mesh.h"
#include "Shader.h"

//Window dimensions
const GLint width = 800, height = 600;
const float toRadians = 3.14159265f / 180.0f;

Window mainWindow;
std::vector<Mesh*> meshList;
std::vector<Shader*> shaderList;

bool direction = true;
float triOffSet = 0.0f;
float triMaxOffSet = 0.7f;
float triIncrement = 0.010f;

float curAngle = 0.0f;

bool sizeDirection = true;
float curSize = 0.4f;
float maxSize = 0.8f;
float minSize = 0.1f;

//Vertex shader
static const char* vShader = "Shaders/shader.vert";

//Fragment shader
static const char* fShader = "Shaders/shader.frag";




void CreateObjects() {
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 3, 1,
        1, 3, 2,
        2, 3, 0,
        0, 1, 2
    };
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };
    Mesh* obj1 = new Mesh();
    obj1->CreateMesh(vertices, indices, 12, 12);
    meshList.push_back(obj1);

    Mesh* obj2 = new Mesh();
    obj2->CreateMesh(vertices, indices, 12, 12);
    meshList.push_back(obj2);

    Mesh* obj3 = new Mesh();
    obj3->CreateMesh(vertices, indices, 12, 12);
    meshList.push_back(obj3);
}

void CreateShaders() {
    Shader *shader1 = new Shader();
    shader1->CreateFromFiles(vShader, fShader);
    shaderList.push_back(shader1);
}

int main() {
    mainWindow = Window(800, 600);
    mainWindow.Initialise();
    CreateObjects();
    CreateShaders();

    GLuint uniformProjection = 0, uniformModel = 0;

    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)mainWindow.getBufferWidth() / mainWindow.getBufferHeight(), 0.1f, 100.0f);

    SDL_Event windowEvent;
    while (true) {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent)) {
            if (windowEvent.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (direction) {
            triOffSet += triIncrement;
        }
        else {
            triOffSet -= triIncrement;
        }

        if (abs(triOffSet) >= triMaxOffSet) {
            direction = !direction;
        }

        curAngle += 1.0f;
        if (curAngle >= 360) {
            curAngle -= 360;
        }

        if (direction) {
            curSize += 0.001f;
        }
        else {
            curSize -= 0.001f;
        }

        if (curSize >= maxSize || curSize <= minSize) {
            sizeDirection = !sizeDirection;
        }

        //Clear window
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        shaderList[0]->UseShader();
        uniformModel = shaderList[0]->GetModelLocation();
        uniformProjection = shaderList[0]->GetProjectionLocation();

        glm::mat4 model(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.5f));
        model = glm::rotate(model, curAngle * toRadians, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f));

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformProjection, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        meshList[0]->RenderMesh();

        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-triOffSet, 1.0f, -2.5f));
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f));

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        meshList[1]->RenderMesh();

        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(triOffSet, -1.0f, -2.5f));
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f));

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        meshList[2]->RenderMesh();

        glUseProgram(0);
        mainWindow.swapWindows();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Mesh.h

```
#pragma once

#include <GL/glew.h>

class Mesh
{
private:
    GLuint VAO, VBO, IBO;
    GLsizei indexCount;
public:
    Mesh();
    void CreateMesh(GLfloat *vertices, unsigned int *indices, unsigned int numOfVertices, unsigned int numOfIndices);
    void RenderMesh();
    void ClearMesh();
    ~Mesh();
};
```

Mesh.cpp

```
#include "Mesh.h"
#include <GL/glew.h>

Mesh::Mesh() {
    VAO = 0;
    VBO = 0;
    IBO = 0;
    indexCount = 0;
}

void Mesh::CreateMesh(GLfloat* vertices, unsigned int* indices, unsigned int numOfVertices, unsigned int numOfIndices) {
    indexCount = numOfIndices;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &IBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices[0]) * numOfIndices, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices[0]) * numOfVertices, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void Mesh::RenderMesh() {
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Mesh::ClearMesh() {
    if (IBO != 0) {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &IBO);
        IBO = 0;
    }
    if (VBO != 0) {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
        VBO = 0;
    }
    if (VAO != 0) {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VAO);
        VAO = 0;
    }
    indexCount = 0;
}
Mesh::~Mesh() {
    ClearMesh();
}
```

Shader.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
class Shader
{
private:
    GLuint shaderID, uniformProjection, uniformModel;
    void CompileShader(const char* vertexCode, const char* fragmentCode);
    void AddShader(GLuint theProgram, const char* shaderCode, GLenum shaderType);
public:
    Shader();
    void CreateFromString(const char* vertexCode, const char* fragmentCode);
    void CreateFromFiles(const char* vertexLocation, const char* fragmentLocation);

    std::string ReadFile(const char* fileLocation);

    GLuint GetProjectionLocation();
    GLuint GetModelLocation();
    void UseShader();
    void ClearShader();
    ~Shader();
};
```

Shader.cpp

```
#include "Shader.h"

Shader::Shader()
{
    shaderID = 0;
    uniformModel = 0;
    uniformProjection = 0;
}

void Shader::CreateFromString(const char* vertexCode, const char* fragmentCode)
{
    CompileShader(vertexCode, fragmentCode);
}


void Shader::CreateFromFiles(const char* vertexLocation, const char* fragmentLocation)
{
    std::string vertexString = ReadFile(vertexLocation);
    std::string fragmentString = ReadFile(fragmentLocation);
    const char* vertexCode = vertexString.c_str();
    const char* fragmentCode = fragmentString.c_str();

    CompileShader(vertexCode, fragmentCode);
}

std::string Shader::ReadFile(const char* fileLocation)
{
    std::string content;
    std::ifstream fileStream(fileLocation, std::ios::in);

    if (!fileStream.is_open()) {
        printf("Failed to read %s! File doesn't exist.", fileLocation);
        return "";
    }

    std::string line = "";
    while (!fileStream.eof())
    {
        std::getline(fileStream, line);
        content.append(line + "\n");
    }

    fileStream.close();
    return content;
}

void Shader::CompileShader(const char* vertexCode, const char* fragmentCode)
{
    shaderID = glCreateProgram();

    if (!shaderID)
    {
        printf("Error creating shader program!\n");
        return;
    }

    AddShader(shaderID, vertexCode, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    AddShader(shaderID, fragmentCode, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLint result = 0;
    GLchar eLog[1024] = { 0 };

    glLinkProgram(shaderID);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderID, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        printf("Error linking program: '%s'\n", eLog);
        return;
    }

    glValidateProgram(shaderID);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderID, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderID, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        printf("Error validating program: '%s'\n", eLog);
        return;
    }

    uniformProjection = glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, "projection");
    uniformModel = glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, "model");
}

GLuint Shader::GetProjectionLocation()
{
    return uniformProjection;
}
GLuint Shader::GetModelLocation()
{
    return uniformModel;
}

void Shader::UseShader()
{
    glUseProgram(shaderID);
}

void Shader::ClearShader()
{
    if (shaderID != 0)
    {
        glDeleteProgram(shaderID);
        shaderID = 0;
    }

    uniformModel = 0;
    uniformProjection = 0;
}


void Shader::AddShader(GLuint theProgram, const char* shaderCode, GLenum shaderType)
{
    GLuint theShader = glCreateShader(shaderType);

    const GLchar* theCode[1];
    theCode[0] = shaderCode;

    GLint codeLength[1];
    codeLength[0] = strlen(shaderCode);

    glShaderSource(theShader, 1, theCode, codeLength);
    glCompileShader(theShader);

    GLint result = 0;
    GLchar eLog[1024] = { 0 };

    glGetShaderiv(theShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(theShader, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        printf("Error compiling the %d shader: '%s'\n", shaderType, eLog);
        return;
    }

    glAttachShader(theProgram, theShader);
}

Shader::~Shader()
{
    ClearShader();
}
```

Window.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>

class Window
{
private:
    SDL_Window* mainWindow;
    SDL_Event windowEvent;
    GLint width, height;
public:
    Window();
    Window(GLint windowWidth, GLint windowHeight);

    int Initialise();
    GLint getBufferWidth() { return width; }
    GLint getBufferHeight() { return height; }

    void swapWindows() { SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainWindow); }
    ~Window();
};
```

Window.cpp

```
#include "Window.h"

Window::Window() {
    width = 800;
    height = 600;
}

Window::Window(GLint width, GLint height) {
    width = width;
    height = height;
}

int Window::Initialise() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("SDL initialisation failed\n");
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);

    mainWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Test game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (!mainWindow) {
        printf("SDL window creation failed!\n");
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    //Set context for GLEW to use
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mainWindow);

    //Allow modern extension features
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        printf("GLEW initialization failed!\n");
        SDL_DestroyWindow(mainWindow);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //Setup viewport size
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
}

Window::~Window() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(mainWindow);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I've heard that a solution to this could be to put glewExperimental = GL_True before glewInit() but that hasn't worked because those two lines are in Window.cpp and I don't know how that could affect Mesh.cpp.

The debug reads this at the bottom:
Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in OpenGLCourseApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

[Call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C3Mn.jpg)

Comment: Please run your process under a debugger and add the stack trace here.

Comment: If you don't get a window, you don't get a context, which means mesh creation will call a function that has not been fetched from the OpenGL dll yet.

Comment: @Botjie just updated the post at the bottom, does this help, or do you need something else?

Comment: No, that's useless. We need an actual stack trace with the functions that were called.

Comment: @Botjie added an image of the call stack, does it help?

Comment: It confirms what I suspected. (see my answer) For your next question(s) about a crash, include a text version from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Window` constructor does not actually initialize the fields of the Window object, which means you call `SDL_CreateWindow` with random `width` and `height`.
Use an initializer list instead, which does not suffer this problem:

```
Window::Window(int width, int height) 
  : width(width), height(height) {
}
```

Once you get past that, keep in mind that the statement

```
mainWindow = Window(800, 600);
```

will create a temporary `Window` object, assign it to `mainWindow`, and then immediately destroy it!
I suggest you change the type of `mainWindow` to `Window*` (or better yet a `std::unique_ptr<Window>`),
 and change that line to

```
mainWindow = new Window(800, 600);
```

or

```
mainWindow = std::make_unique<Window>(800, 600);
```

Comment: Sorry @Botje , I'm slightly confused here, could you give an example of your implementation in my code please?

Comment: change the definition of `Window::Window` with my version, change the declaration of `Window mainWindow` to `Window * mainWindow`, change the initialization to what I posted above, and change all uses of `mainWindow` to use `->` instead of `.`